# Is Every Set Open in the Subspace Topology on the Cantor Set?

Tags: general-topology

Im working in the real line with the usual topology.

For the cantor set subspace of R, let T represent the the subspace topology on the cantor set induced by the usual topology.

I'm trying to show that T is not equal to the power set topology on the cantor set.

I'm really lost on what to do here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If by "power set topology" you mean "every set is open", then the solution is simple. Show that there are subsets of the Cantor set which are not open.

More specifically, you can show that no singleton is open.